# phpmyadmin offers the file for download instead

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, spdy

I have a problem: on my server phpmyadmin doesn't work anymore.
it offers the file db_structure.php for download instead of parsing it .

once downloaded it has 0KB

I already removed it with atp-get purge and reinstalled it, but still the same
what could be wrong?

maybe a module missing that phpmyadmin is using? cause all other php files work on my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason:

i had the beta version of googles spdy:// protocol included on my server and this caused the error.

i disabled it in

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enebled/
```

and everything went fine again

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem.

Try following command. This is solved my problem.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

In general, download instead of running is caused by not installed/enabled php module.

You may also enable the php apache module using:

```
sudo apt-get install php
sudo a2enmod php
```